# Pandas dataframe list iteration with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a job which runs every 15 mins and returns an IP array list like this

```
listofIPs = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
```

I maintain this in a masterlist.csv file against the date like this.

```
IP,Timestamp
1.1.1.1,2022-05-12_2030
2.2.2.2,2022-05-12_2030
3.3.3.3,2022-05-12_2030
5.5.5.5,2022-05-12_1430
8.8.8.8,2022-05-11_1930
1.1.1.1,2022-05-06_2030
```

**Every 15 mins the job returns some IP list.We need to check if any IP from the list is NOT present in master csv in last 24 hours and then only append that IP to master csv file**

I want to achieve this using Pandas dataframes or basic python,and not Pyspark etc

I have tried something like this but it didn't work

```
   mainfile = '/Users/Documents/masterlist.csv'
   runtime = datetime.strftime(now , '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M')
   listofIPs = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
  
   dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M')
   df = pd.read_csv(mainfile, parse_dates=['Timestamp'], date_parser=dateparse)
   recent_df = df[df.timestamp > datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("1day")]
   badip_df = recent_df.drop_duplicates("IP", keep='last')
   
   if badip_df.empty:
        badip_df['Timestamp'] = runtime
        badip_df = badip_df[[listofIPs, 'Timestamp']]
        badip_df.to_csv(mainfile, index=False)
    else:
        badip_df.to_csv(mainfile, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is the error message from your code?

Comment: Its not appending to the list somehow

Comment: it seems `goodfp_df` is not defined before being called

Comment: @BlackRaven i edited my code. goodfp_df doesnt exist.It was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be the requested solution. It appends only the new IPs to the CSV file (I changed 1.1.1.1 to 1.1.1x as example):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

mainfile = 'masterlist.csv'
runtime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M')
listofIPs = ['1.1.1.x', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']

dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M')
df = pd.read_csv(mainfile, parse_dates=['Timestamp'], 
date_parser=dateparse)
recent_df = df[df.Timestamp > datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("100 days")]
unique_ip_df = recent_df.drop_duplicates("IP", keep='last')

unique_ip_df.Timestamp = unique_ip_df.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: 
datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d_%H%M'))
complete_df = unique_ip_df.append([{'IP': IP, 'Timestamp': runtime} for IP in listofIPs if not IP in unique_ip_df.IP.values])
complete_df.to_csv(mainfile, mode='w', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @hansestadt_greifswald ..This worked fine. Is it because i was appending as 'a' this issue was happening?

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.strftime`, `datetime.strptime`, and `datetime.now()` don't exist. All of those are methods of `datetime.datetime`, e.g. `datetime.datetime.now()` [EDIT: oh, unless you imported using `from datetime import datetime`].

Also, as mentioned in the comments, `goodfp_df` is not defined before it is first used. Fix those problems, and you'll be somewhere. Is it supposed to be defined as `recent_df[~recentdf.duplicated(keep=False)]`, by any chance?

Also, `df.timestamp` should be `df.Timestamp`, and `now` isn't defined (should be `datetime.now()`).

Finally, `listofIPs` is a list and thus can't be a column title of a dataframe.

Comment: I edited my code..It was a typo.Its just badip_df and yes i have imported the datetime packages

Comment: Do you intend to overwrite your master list when there are no bad IPs, by the way? Because that is what your code will do.

Comment: No i dont intend to overwrite the master list when there are no bad IPs

Comment: Your write when `badip_df` is empty should then be an append.

Comment: Well how i envisioned it was it there is no entry in the master csv file then just dump whatever IP list my job finds but if there is some data already then i want to check the IP list has new IP not found in last 24 hrs and just append that IP to the master csv